# Return a name matching two values

Tags: excel, formula

I have a table of data in one worksheet and some analysis in a second. In the 'Data' worksheet each row contains a name and then a range of values (numerical). What I need to do is look across each row and where, for example, columns `PN` and `PM` both contain a `1` return me the name in column `M`. This list needs to then grow as I add more data to the table in 'Data'.

Hopefully that makes sense. I am doing something similar with a single value lookup using the below but cannot get it to work for multiple values:

```
=IF(ISERROR(INDEX(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999,SMALL(IF(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999=$J$6,ROW(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999)),ROW(1:1))-1,13)),"",INDEX(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999,SMALL(IF(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999=$J$6,ROW(Data!$A$4:$QQ$4999)),ROW(1:1))-3,13))
```

I copy this down and then when the data is updated the blank cells are automatically populated. The new formula I need is similar to this, but rather than looking up one value `J6` in the above, I need to lookup two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a *helper column*.  Pick an unused column, say column **QR** and in cell **QR4** enter:

```
=IF(AND(PM4=1,PN4=1),1,0)
```

In **QR5** enter:

```
=IF(AND(PM5=1,PN5=1),1+MAX($QR$4:QR4),0)
```

and copy downward.

This column assigns a simple sequential value for each "collectable" row.  For example:

[image]

Then in the other sheet, pick any cell and enter:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!M$4:M$4999,MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Data!QR$4:QR$4999,0)),"")
```

and copy down to collect the data:

[image]

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you. However, I would also like in another cell next to the name returned the row number that the name is in.

Comment: @Adam  Then just use the **MATCH()** part of the formula remembering that this is relative to the start of the data-table.

Comment: Ah thanks Gary. I missed out a part. Have it working now. Thanks again. I used: =IFERROR(MATCH(ROWS($1:1),Data!QR$4:QR$4999,0)+3,"")